# Can't create a slider (<rzslider>) in the UI

Tags: html, angularjs

### Is this code is correct to run ? because i have a question that is tag will execute without any built in libraries of

can this `<rzslider>` tag run directly in the page without any built-in packages of `<rzslider>`

running it using linux server.

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.minValue" 
   rz-slider-high="slider.maxValue" 
   rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>
```

```js
$scope.slider = { 
   minValue: 10, 
   maxValue: 90, 
   options: { 
   floor: 0, 
   ceil: 100, 
   step: 1 
  }
};
```

using this tags i can't able to create a slider in the UI. so how can i execute  it to show the slider in the UI?

Comment: How exactly do you "run" that code? What should that code do?

Comment: the code should create a multi slider

Comment: rzslider  is component or directive?

Comment: it is an html tag

Comment: [rzslider or "AngularJS Slider"](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider) is an AngularJS 1 component using the custom HTML tag `<rzslider>` as target element to create a graphical value slider.

Comment: Read [Github angular-slider/angularjs-slider Project Integration](https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider#project-integration). Or [NPM angularjs-slider Project Integration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularjs-slider#project-integration).

Answer (score 0):

You should try  like as below

**In view**

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.value"
          rz-slider-options="slider.options">
</rzslider>
```

**In controller**

```
$scope.slider = {
    value: 10,
    options: {
        floor: 7,
        ceil: 10,
        showTicks: true,
        showSelectionBar: true,
        hidePointerLabels: true,
        hideLimitLabels: true,
        showTicksValues: false,
        readOnly: true,
        getTickColor: function (value) {
            if (value < 3)
              return 'red';
            if (value < 6)
              return 'orange';
            if (value < 9)
              return 'yellow';
            return '#2AE02A';
        }
    },
}
```

Make sure you have add `rzSlider` module in your `app.js`

Comment: The name of the module is `'rzSlider'` not `rzModule`.